# Filter (xml-)Data with Where-Object count ... in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in PowerShell:

```
[xml]$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>False</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-B</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-C</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageStart>2019-07-23T18:53:58.392+02:00</PackageStart>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.392+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-D</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageStart>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageStart>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
</Sequences>
"@

Clear-Host

$Sequences = $Xml.Sequences.Sequence | Where-Object ...
$Sequences
```

As you see, I load XML-Data and then I want to filter it with "Where-Object". 
In the XML, we see 2 Sequence-nodes containing 2 package-nodes each.

I want to select those "Sequence" node(s), that have:

- At least one Active Package. A Package is Active, when there is ( NO  node ) OR (  IS TRUE )
  (In the example Package-A is not active)
- At least one package has no end-time (Attribute "PackageEnd")

In this example, the result of the query should be "Sequence-A", because it does have a package, which does NOT contain the attribute "PackageActive" and both packages have no end-time (Attribute "PackageEnd" is not set).

Ideally I am looking for a one-liner ...

Thank you in advance for your support!

**EDIT:**
I did add further examples for clarification ...

```
[xml]$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>False</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-B</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-C</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.392+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-D</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-C</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-E</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>False</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-F</PackageFolder>
        <PackageMeta>
          <PackageEnd>2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00</PackageEnd>
        </PackageMeta>      
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-D</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-G</PackageFolder>
        <PackageActive>True</PackageActive>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package-H</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>  
</Sequences>
"@
```

- Sequence-A should be selected. Package-A won't be processed, but Package-B does NOT contain a PackageEnd-node.
- Sequence-B should NOT be selected. Both packages contain a PackageEnd-node.
- Sequence-C should NOT be selected. Package-E is NOT Active and Package-F contains a PackageEnd-node.
- Sequence-D should be selected. Package-G is Active and Package-H also. Both Packages do not contain a PackageEnd-node.

Comment: XML files are usually queried using XPath. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)'s a pretty good tutorial on XPath in general, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-6) is how to use it in PowerShell. .NET's [SelectNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.8) can also be used to query with XPath syntax and is very easy to use. I'd recommend going this route over trying to use `Where-Object`.

Comment: Your situation will more than likely be more than a one-liner because of all the logic required to get the data you are interested in.

Comment: `$xml.SelectNodes('//Sequence[.//Package[not(./PackageActive)] and .//Package[not(.//PackageEnd)]]')`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have never worked with XPath till now. At the moment this seems to be working fine. Why don't you post this as solution? Do you see any problem?

Comment: The only drawback I did find till now is, that when I set PackageActive to "True" it is not working anymore. (Ofc I did not request this) Would there be an easy fix for this too?

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer b/c I was not certain that the condition reflects what you were asking. Are you looking for `<Sequence>` nodes where a `<Package>` node doesn't have both a `<PackageActive>` and a `<PackageEnd>` descendant? A node with a `<Package>` node without a `<PackageActive>` node and a `<Package>` node without a `<PackageEnd>` node, even if there is no node with both descendants absent? A node where one or the other absent?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I did edit my request and added some examples for clarification. I hope this will answer your questions.

Comment: Is this an assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following one-liner seems to be the solution:

```
$Sequences = $Xml.Sequences.SelectNodes( "//Sequence[.//Package[(./PackageActive/text()='True' or not(./PackageActive)) and not(.//PackageEnd)]]" )
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pipe this to a where-object filter pretty easily.  I used the second xml example.  Maybe the xml could be designed better.  Packagemeta doesn't show up under $xml.sequences.sequence.sequencepackages.package, unless you pipe it to format-list.  I only put the outer foreach in side the `& { }` so you can pipe from it.

```
& { 
  foreach ($s in $xml.sequences.sequence) {
    foreach ($p in $s.sequencepackages.package) {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        sequencename = $s.sequencename
        packagefolder = $p.packagefolder
        packageactive = $p.packageactive
        packageend = $p.packagemeta.packageend
      }
    }
  } 
}


sequencename packagefolder packageactive packageend
------------ ------------- ------------- ----------
Sequence-A   Package-A     False
Sequence-A   Package-B
Sequence-B   Package-C                   2019-07-23T18:53:58.392+02:00
Sequence-B   Package-D                   2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00
Sequence-C   Package-E     False
Sequence-C   Package-F                   2019-07-23T18:53:58.407+02:00
Sequence-D   Package-G     True
Sequence-D   Package-H
```

Comment: This is great and I really love this solution, but it seems, that I am not able to simply plug this in into my project. I did already make use of XML-methods and so on. I would have to rewrite the whole project. However I will keep a solution like this in mind for future use. Thank you for the effort. I will mark your answer as useful.